# How to slice array of awk-output in bash?

Tags: bash, awk

## Summary

Depending on what `bash` or `awk` version I have, I get different results when I try to slice an array that holds `awk` output. On older versions of `bash` and `awk` the "slice operation" ( e.g. `${a[@]:2}`) incorrectly returns an array with a single element regardless of how many elements are left in the sliced array. However, this only seems to be an issue when slicing arrays that "capture" `awk` output.

## MWE

- You can run the following to reproduce the issue:

  ```
    bash array_slice.sh text.file
  ```

  where `array_slice.sh` and `text.file` are the following:
- `array_slice.sh` script:

  ```
     #!/usr/bin/env bash                                                        

     defaultIFS=$IFS                                                            
     IFS=$'\n'                                                                  
     t=($(awk '{ printf("%s\n", $0) }' "$1"))                                   
     printf "\nArray 't' has ${#t[@]} elements\n"                               
     printf "Elements of array 't':\n"                                          
     printf "%s\n" "${t[@]}"                                                    

     t45=( ${t[@]:4} )                                                          
     printf "\nArray 't45' has ${#t45[@]} elements\n"                           
     printf "Elements of array 't45':\n"                                        
     printf "%s\n" "${t45[@]}"
  ```
- `text.file` :

  ```
    some text                                                                   
    some other text                                                             
    this is text too                                                            
    text above is text                                                          
    and text below is text text                                                 
    text text
  ```

## Output for various platforms

Notice how array `t45` only has one element in Ubuntu 16.04's output (it's supposed to have two) and how it correctly has two elements in Ubuntu 20.04's output.

- Ubuntu 16.04 with

  - GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)
  - GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    Gives:

  ```
    Array 't' has 6 elements
    Elements of array 't':
    some text
    some other text
    this is text too
    text above is text
    and text below is text text
    text text

    Array 't45' has 1 elements
    Elements of array 't45':
    and text below is text text text text
  ```
- Ubuntu 20.04 with

  - GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)
  - GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    Gives:

  ```
  Array 't' has 6 elements
  Elements of array 't':
  some text
  some other text
  this is text too
  text above is text
  and text below is text text
  text text

  Array 't45' has 2 elements
  Elements of array 't45':
  and text below is text text
  text text
  ```

Comment: Please confirm you don't want `t45=( "${t[@]:4}" )`. If you want to build an array from exact elements of another array then you should quote. If you want to create a string that possibly gets split again then don't quote. I believe you there's a difference when you don't quote. I cannot fully explain this behavior yet. Maybe you want to research the phenomenon for educational reasons or whatever. But *maybe* you observed the behavior in circumstances where the right thing is to double-quote in the first place.

Comment: Quoting works on the MWE. I've checked on Ubuntu (16.04, 20.04), Windows, and MacOS (though on MacOS I needed to install a new bash). It seems that with really old bash versions, such as the default MacOS one, even the quoting doesn't work. However, I believe the quoting solution will work where in the use case that I need to solve.